# The error "TypeError: dest.on is not a function" for gulp-webp when trying to convert images

Tags: image, compiler-errors, gulp, development-environment, webp

I have an issue with a task in my code. I have some images and I'd like to convert them from .jpg to .webp using the "gulp-webp" module but when I'm run the gulp function on the termial the following error appears:

```
[00:00:00]Starting 'versionWebp'...
[00:00:00]'versionWebp' errored after 8.92 msTypeError: dest.on is not a function
[00:00:00]at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (D:\Cursos\Curso 06\FestivalMusica_inicio\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:564:8)
at versionWebp (D:\Cursos\Curso 06\FestivalMusica_inicio\gulpfile.js:60:10)
at taskWrapper (D:\Cursos\Curso 06\FestivalMusica_inicio\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
at bound (node:domain:421:15)
at runBound (node:domain:432:12)
at asyncRunner (D:\Cursos\Curso 06\FestivalMusica_inicio\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11).
```

My code is this

```
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const webp = require ('gulp-webp');

function versionWebp(){
return src('src/img/**/*')
    .pipe( webp )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'))
    .pipe(notify({message:'Version WEBP'}));
};

exports.versionWebp = versionWebp;
```

I hope you could help me.

Comment: Use `.pipe(webp())` instead of `.pipe(webp)`.

Answer (score 0):

webp must have `()` at the end, must be a function; the code will be:

```
function versionWebp(){
   return src('src/img/**/*')
      .pipe( webp() )
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'))
      .pipe(notify({message:'Version WEBP'}));
};
```